# How to prove $10^n$ is the smallest $n+1$ digit number?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

It seems obvious that $10$ is the smallest 2 digit number and $100$ is the smallest 3 digit number.

In fact, it seems a little obvious to me that $10^n$ is the smallest $n+1$ digit number.

But how do I prove this without any assumptions?

Answer (score 3):

Well, one should start out by looking at what a decimal representation is: It is a representation of a number $x$ as a sum of powers of ten multiplied by digits. That is, a decimal representation with $n$ digits is a sum of the form
$$x=a_0+10\cdot a_1+100\cdot a_2+\ldots+ 10^{n-1}\cdot a_{n-1}$$
where each of the $a_i$ an integers between $0$ and $9$.

Now, it's pretty easy to see that the largest number with an $n$ digit representation is the one where all of $a_i$ are as big as possible - that is, they're all $9$. Thus the largest $x$ with an $n$ digit representation is
$$x=9+10\cdot 9 + 100\cdot 9 + \ldots + 10^{n-1}\cdot 9 = \underbrace{99\ldots 99}_{n\text{ times}}=10^n-1$$
One can prove by induction that all smaller positive numbers are indeed representable with $n$ digits. Obviously, we have that $10^n$ requires at least $n+1$ digits to represent and, given that all smaller numbers require only $n$ digits, it follows that $10^n$ is the smallest number requiring $n+1$ digits.

(Note that I use the terminology of requiring $n+1$ digits, since I can totally write $1=0001$ as a four digit representation of $1$. It's just not the smallest representation)

Comment: I believe you have a couple of typos. $10^n$ requires at least $n + 1$ digits, and all smaller numbers require only $n$ digits.

Comment: @Synergist Thanks for catching that; I now fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

In order to prove something, you need to define it. However, 99% of mathematics is independent of the representation of numbers, so in order to prove this the easiest way is to invent a property of $x$ that corresponds to its number of digits. This is the output of the function $$f_b(x)=\lfloor\log_b(x)\rfloor+1$$

This function tells you how many digits the (positive real) number $x$ has in base $b$. It's a simple mater to now prove that $$f_b(b^n-\varepsilon)<n+1=f_b(b^n)$$ by showing that this function is strictly increasing.

Comment: So basically find the line between $x$ digits and $x+1$ digits?

Comment: Yup. The reason many proofs about rational numbers begin "let x=p/q in lowest form" is the same. Even when representation of numbers matters, it's just so much easier to translate the property into a representation independent one, so that you can use the rest of mathematics. You can give definitions for number of digits that do depend on how the number is represented, but then you couldn't use any theorems about increasing functions because they might not maintain that difference.

Comment: Thank you for this beautiful "proof." (close enough to a proof anyways)

Comment: I'm not sure one can reasonably assert this property as a definition. It's true and a common fact, but it follows from how positional notation is defined, rather than being a definition in itself. That this is non-trivial becomes more visible if one considers [less standard systems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-standard_positional_numeral_systems) where one has analogous definitions, but different results on the number of digits required. (Floating point numbers may also provide an example where the number of digits might not follow an obvious law and would clearly require derivation)

Answer (score 1):

By definition the number $N$ written as $a_n\;a_{n-1}\;...\;a_0$ in base 10 (where $a_k$ are its $n+1$ decimal digits) represents the value $a_n 10^n + a_{n-1} 10^{n-1} + ... a_1 10 + a_0$. Assuming the first digit $a_n \ne 0$ it follows that the number $N \ge 10^n$.